# Right part of UIScrollView doesn't work in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Using the Interface Builder, I created a view with a UIScrollView in it.

I programmaticly add the buttons to the empty UIScrollView.

When the orientation changes, I use

```
 - (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

to call a method that resets the buttons on screen.

After that, the **uiScrollView**-content gets a new size using **setContentSize**.

No matter the width of the **ContentSize**, I can only interact (scroll/or tap a button) on the first 320px of the screen - which is the screen width in portrait mode.

[image: Example]

When I set the **contentSize-width** to 2000, I can scroll to the left, but only with my fingers on the first 320 px instead of the full 480 (using a 3.5 inch iPhone).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resize the scrollview's frame, not just the content size (in fact, often you *don't* need to resize the content size, as the content may not change following an orientation change, but just the frame).

Comment: I set the frame in **willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation**, but no results.

Comment: do you have other views and/or gesture recognizers outside of the scroll view?

Comment: How dump! I overlooked another parent view, which wasn't resized. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Popup (UIView) that was called from a (UIViewController).

In the UIViewController the popup was created as followed

```
func createPopup() {
    let myPopup = MyPopup(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(myPopup)
}
```

In the Popup (UIView) I needed to override layoutSubviews as follows:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.setNeedsDisplay()

    let mainScreenBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    view.frame = mainScreenBounds
    super.frame = mainScreenBounds <-- Need to update the parent

    ** perform additional rotation/orientation code here **
}
```